# "Rollback" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

A **["rollback"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback)** in Stack Exchange is an action to get a post back to a certain revision in its history.

It even has the badge [*Cleanup*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) for those doing it for the first time.

I was wondering: how can this be translated to Spanish? Checking in [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=rollback) I see some suggestions like "reducción", "retirada" or "revocación", but neither of them sound very well to me.

Comment: La primera palabra que se me ocurre es *revuelta* que se define en parte como «Punto en que algo empieza a torcer su dirección o a tomar otra / Este mismo cambio de dirección / Vuelta o mudanza de un estado a otro, o de un parecer a otro».  Otra ventaja: existe el verbo *revolver* también: «Volver a andar lo andado. / Dicho de una cosa: Dar vuelta entera hasta llegar al punto de donde salió»

Comment: @guifa Ya veremos lo que harán para la IU de es.so, pero a mí me parece mejor un verbo en este caso, aunque no me importa tanto que sea *revertir* o *restaurar* o algún otro.

Comment: Revertir o restaurar son las mejores opciones.

Comment: Pues veo que finalmente [es.so] utiliza _revertir_ ([un ejemplo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/21314/revisions)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest to "*do a rollback*" the verb **restaurar**.

But for substantive *rollback* none word sounds good to me. *Restauración, reposición, restablecimiento...* not seem usual to talk about records, operating systems or databases. Maybe a phrase: **vuelta atrás**.

Comment: Restaurar and vuelta atrás are right on point. Great answer.

Comment: *Restaurar* seems to be the best option. In Windows if you create a restore point (English version) Punto de restauración (Spanish version) you can Rollback (restaurar a un punto de restauración / restaurar sistema).

Answer (score 14):

I suggest you to use **`revertir`**.

Comment: This si the correct usage :)

Comment: I agree. In IT jargon, to rollback is a general term meaning to undo any change leaving the system as it was before such change was done. It's translated as _revertir_ by spanish spoken sysadmins. If the rollback is done just by restoring a backup copy, then we use _restaurar_.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the word "Rebobinar" (*Rewind*), "Restaurar" (*To restore*), or maybe "Retroceder" (*To go back*). As a substantives, there are *Rebobinado*, *Restauración*, and *Retroceso*

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> Volver a una versión anterior.

Answer (score 1):

If the post is changed to the previous version the correct word would be

**revertir**: Come back to a previous version.

**reversionar**: (Not in the sense of remake), but to change the version

Other options:

**recuperar**