# ¿Hay alguna forma de traducir al español "commit", hablando de bases de datos?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

No creo que sea necesario traducirlo, pero tengo la curiosidad.

Cuando termino de enviar todas mis instrucciones a la base de datos y estoy seguro de que todo ha ido bien, "*hago un commit*", es decir, le doy el visto bueno a la base de datos para que haga efectivos los cambios. La otra posibilidad es "*hacer un rollback*", que ya se discutió en [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13454/6915).

¿Hay alguna forma de decirlo en español, ya sea el sustantivo ("un commit") o el verbo ("hacer un commit")? "Cometer" creo no viene al caso porque se usa principalmente con delitos y pecados.

Comment: Para mí, _to commit_ en informática es algo así como [_acometer_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0X7ng6k) o [_perpetrar_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ShkiRQi). Es decir, proceder a ejecutar algo. No conozco ninguna palabra específica y, como tantas otras veces, oigo con frecuencia "cuando termines con esto haz un _commit_ y luego _push_".

Comment: Yo también lo veo asociado a comprometer: al _comprometerte_ con los datos, los oficializas, dejándolos visibles para el resto.

Comment: No hay traducción establecida, y no conviene traducirla en un ambiente técnico (hay menos probabilidades de que se entienda la traducción que la palabra original en inglés). Informalmente, he oído (y usado, confieso) los engendros "comitear" y "rollbackear"... :-)

Comment: El [diccionario Oxford online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/commit) dice que _commit_ significa, en esta acepción, "transferir algo a donde se lo pueda guardar o conservar", por lo que _transferir_ (y sus sinónimos) deberían ser aceptables en teoría pero, como ya dijeron, no hay ninguna traducción establecida.

Comment: En este caso la equivalencia más cecana sería *comprometer*. Personalmente, yo no usaría esta palabra dentro del contexto de las bases de datos si estuviera escribiendo o traduciendo un manual; en su lugar usarí algo como **hacer *commit***

Comment: Yo lo traduciría por `consolidar` o `hacer definitivo/a` un cambio o modificación.

Comment: @Jdamian, veo que llevas ya bastante tiempo en el foro, pero nunca has escrito una respuesta. ¿Te animas a hacerlo ahora? No se pregunta si hay una traducción de uso general, sino que se pide una forma de decirlo en castellano, y creo que tu propuesta de *consolidar* es muy buena.

Comment: @JDamian, le encuentro toda la razón a Gorpik, _consolidar_ está re buena. Convierte tu comentario en respuesta tal como está y te la acepto.

Comment: Yo me decantaría por *confirmar*.

Comment: @Gorpik, gracias, pero ocurre que a veces no tengo tiempo para ello. Hoy en cambio sí he podido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que **confirmar** es una opción correcta. En base de datos se *confirman* los cambios para que sean permanentes.

En la versión española de la aplicación para *[Git](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)* *(TortoiseSVN)* el equipo de traducción eligió esta palabra.

- https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-glossary.html
- https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_es/tsvn-glossary.html

Answer (score 2):

Yo la traduciría por **consolidar**.

En bases de datos se utiliza el concepto de *[transacción](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transacci%C3%B3n_%28base_de_datos%29)* que, según me explicaron hace ya muchos años, es en realidad un conjunto de operaciones básicas o *atómicas* (*insert*, *update*, etc) íntimamente relacionadas entre sí, las cuales no tienen sentido por separado. En ellas, un solo fallo en cualquiera de esas operaciones básicas hace que la transacción sea cancelada (*roll back*), deshaciendo incluso aquellas operaciones básicas que sí han terminado sin fallos; de lo contrario la información guardada sería inconsistente.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, Jdamian. ¡Gracias y bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Tras muy buenos comentarios, es bueno verte también respondiendo : )

Answer (score 0):

En efecto consolidar la operaciones realizadas es la mejor traducción, puesto que refleja su función: hacer permanentes una serie de operaciones. Al contrario, el rollback deshace dichas operaciones.
Aunque implícitamente supone que hacemos una confirmación, traducir commit por confirmar sería semanticamente incompleto.

Answer (score 0):

... y este es el motivo por el que es mala idea traducir "commit", "rollback", etc.

Esas palabras tienen un significado técnico muy estricto en el ámbito de las bases de datos y, además, la instrucción se llama literalmente así. Aunque hay buenas razones para utilizar ciertas traducciones, no vamos a terminar de entendernos.

Sobre *confirmar*, esta charla entre programadores sería verosímil:

> - He *confirmado* los cambios en la base de datos.
> - ¿Qué?
> - ¡Que he hecho commit!
> - ¡Ah!

Sí, por ahí se oye "*comitear*" y cosas peores...

Sobre *consolidar*, el problema es que se usa en el mismo ámbito, pero para otra cosa diferente, conocida como *data consolidation*:

> La consolidación de datos es el proceso de combinar datos de múltiples fuentes, limpiarlos y verificarlos eliminando errores y almacenarlos en una única ubicación
> (https://www.astera.com/es/type/blog/data-consolidation/)